# Function and data shortcuts ambiguity .x, ~

Tags: r, shortcut

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(gapminder)
#> Warning: package 'gapminder' was built under R version 3.6.2
gap <- gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == "Asia") %>%
  mutate(yr1952 = year - 1952)

gap_nested <- gap %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  nest()

gap_nested
#> # A tibble: 33 x 2
#> # Groups:   country [33]
#>    country          data             
#>    <fct>            <list>           
#>  1 Afghanistan      <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  2 Bahrain          <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  3 Bangladesh       <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  4 Cambodia         <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  5 China            <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  6 Hong Kong, China <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  7 India            <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  8 Indonesia        <tibble [12 x 6]>
#>  9 Iran             <tibble [12 x 6]>
#> 10 Iraq             <tibble [12 x 6]>
#> # ... with 23 more rows
gap_nested$data[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#>    continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap yr1952
#>    <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.      0
#>  2 Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.      5
#>  3 Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.     10
#>  4 Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.     15
#>  5 Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.     20
#>  6 Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.     25
#>  7 Asia       1982    39.9 12881816      978.     30
#>  8 Asia       1987    40.8 13867957      852.     35
#>  9 Asia       1992    41.7 16317921      649.     40
#> 10 Asia       1997    41.8 22227415      635.     45
#> 11 Asia       2002    42.1 25268405      727.     50
#> 12 Asia       2007    43.8 31889923      975.     55

gap_fitted <- gap_nested %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(lifeExp ~ yr1952, data = .x)))
gap_fitted
#> # A tibble: 33 x 3
#> # Groups:   country [33]
#>    country          data              fit   
#>    <fct>            <list>            <list>
#>  1 Afghanistan      <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  2 Bahrain          <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  3 Bangladesh       <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  4 Cambodia         <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  5 China            <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  6 Hong Kong, China <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  7 India            <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  8 Indonesia        <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#>  9 Iran             <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#> 10 Iraq             <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>  
#> # ... with 23 more rows
gap_fitted$fit[[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = lifeExp ~ yr1952, data = .x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       yr1952  
#>     29.9073       0.2753

gap_fitted <- gap_fitted %>%
  mutate(
    intercept = map_dbl(fit, ~ coef(.x)[["(Intercept)"]]),
    slope = map_dbl(fit, ~ coef(.x)[["yr1952"]])
  )
gap_fitted
#> # A tibble: 33 x 5
#> # Groups:   country [33]
#>    country          data              fit    intercept slope
#>    <fct>            <list>            <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Afghanistan      <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        29.9 0.275
#>  2 Bahrain          <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        52.7 0.468
#>  3 Bangladesh       <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        36.1 0.498
#>  4 Cambodia         <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        37.0 0.396
#>  5 China            <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        47.2 0.531
#>  6 Hong Kong, China <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        63.4 0.366
#>  7 India            <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        39.3 0.505
#>  8 Indonesia        <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        36.9 0.635
#>  9 Iran             <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        45.0 0.497
#> 10 Iraq             <tibble [12 x 6]> <lm>        50.1 0.235
#> # ... with 23 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Can anyone explain to me the actual text that goes in the place of shortcuts used in the above code like ~, .x. Sometimes simple "." will be used.  Is there package which substitutes actual names in place of those shortcuts.  Is the pronoun .x indicates the data argument in the map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol ~ indicates you're dealing with a formula.

In the rlang package (and by extention in the tidyverse packages) a formula can be interpreted as a anonymous function.

Therefore if you write:

```
map(data, ~ lm(lifeExp ~ yr1952, data = .x))
```

It's like writing:

```
map(data, function(x) lm(lifeExp ~ yr1952, data = x))
```

The first method is really useful and more readable than a anonymous function.

When you deal with more than one input you can also use `.y` or even `..1`, `..2`, etc.

The function that allows the magic is `purrr::as_mapper` that eventually calls `rlang::as_function`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sometimes I will see only . in expressions for example in facet wrap, we have facet_wrap(. ~ drive)  what function . and ~ are doing here and can you explain the .x usage in `map_dbl(fit, ~ coef(.x)[["(Intercept)"]])`

Comment: The `.x` usage in `map_dbl(fit, ~ coef(.x)[["(Intercept)"]])` is exactly the same I explained you in my answer. It is needed as a replacement of the anonymous function. I think `ggplot2` was created before this logic, so `facet_grid` works differently. In that case you're representing the formula: `columns ~ rows`. When you see `.` is because columns is not specified. in `facet_wrap` you can't specify rows and columns, so you just omit the left side with a dot and add multiple vars on the right: `. ~ var1 + var2`

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give a link to understand these notations .y, ..1, ..2

Comment: look at `help(purrr::map2)`. The examples are really good.

Comment: In the following video, https://youtu.be/NY0-IFet5AM?t=1461 I wonder the arguments inside the sum and mean are doing. Can anyone explain? `~sum( . > 0) and ~mean(.[depicted > 0])`